# Comparing vectors in APL

Tags: vector, apl

I would like to check whether 2 vectors are the same in APL. Right now I am using the following solution (comparing element by element, summing the elements and comparing with size of vector `a`):

```
a←1 2 3
b←1 2 3
(+/a=b)=⍴a ⍝ it needs to return 0 or 1
```

Is there any quicker or more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the match function which compares its entire arguments rather than equals which is a scalar function that compares the elements of each argument:

```
       a←1 2 3
       b←1 2 3 4 5
       c←1 2 3
      a≡b
0
      a≡c
1
```

Comment: In connection to what David Siegel wrote, Match fails if any 0 element is compared to an almost-zero one, even though ⎕CT (comparison tolerance) exceeds the difference. E.g. `3 2 1 0 ≡ 3 2 1 1E¯100`.

Answer (score 1):

The match primitive, as mentioned above, returns 1 if the arguments are exactly identical. This means that they have the exact same rank, shape, data type, and content. In a few cases match will return a false negative because of data-type issues (division resulting in a floating point representation, even though it is within the comparison tolerance of an integer), or because a scaler will not match a 1-element vector.

^/a=b

will return a 1 if all elements of a test equal to corresponding elements of b, but it will fail with a LENGTH error if a and b are of different lengths, and it will use scaler extension, so that if a is 1 1 1 and b is a scaler 1, the result will be 1.

Match is usually better for this, and it is also more efficient on large arrays.